# Is it possible to maintain the last image of the baked fluid simulation as a still?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation, baking

I made a fluid simulation for fog (frame 1 to 10), and I want the fog to remain as it is at frame 10. I'm animating something else in the file until frame 260, but I want the fog to remain as it as in frame 10 without baking it all the way to 260. The fog still shows in the rest of the frames in the viewport shading, however in the renderings (Cycles) it only shows up until frame 10, then it disappears. How can I "freeze" the fog at frame 10 until the end (260) without baking it all the way?
Thanks!

Comment: The answer is here for anyone looking in the future: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prcaYsujY-U